# Android question about TableLayout and ellipsis

Tags: android, xml, layout, tablelayout

I'm having a problem with my TableLayout. It consists of two columns and multiple rows. When the TextView of the second column contains text of a longer width, then it pushes the TextView's in that column (in the below rows) off of the screen (to the right). Instead, I want it to keep the text to the left and have it cap the text at the end with an ellipsis. Can anyone see what's wrong with my XML?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#4096cc" >

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedshape"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Server Name"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtServerName"
                android:text=""
                android:gravity="right"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:padding="10dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Status"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dip" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />
        </TableRow>
            .
            .
            .

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on which column you want to put the cap on, you need to use

```
android:shrinkColumns=x
```

in your `TableLayout` where x is the index of the column you want to ellipsize.

You probably also want to set the maxLines on the `TextView` to 1 as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I wasn't aware of shrinkColumns. I tried that, however, and for some reason it's making the row very tall in height and also the whole row across the width of the screen is the 2nd column...I can't see the first column at all. The text in the 2nd column is also not capping with an ellipsis. Any ideas?

Comment: 2 is the correct value for your layout.  The column those TextViews that you want to shrink are in the second-indexed (third) column.  You started in the second column by setting layout_column equal to 1.  That is also a zero-indexed attribute.

Comment: Okay, I made a minor adjustment and used android:stretchColumns="1"
 and android:shrinkColumns="2", and everything looks good. Thank you for your help!